# Scala/Spark DataFrame: join rows to get a pair within itself

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to write a function that will tranform df -> df2 as follows:

```
// input dataframe df
+-----+-----+
|  T  |  S  |
+-----+-----+
|    A|   4|
|    B|   8|
|    C|   8|
|    D|   2|
+-----+-----+
```

I need a function that will take `df` as input and return `df2` as output.

```
// output dataframe df2
+-----+-----+-----+
| T1 | T2 | S=T1+T2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    B|  12|
|    A|    C|  12|
|    A|    D|  6|
|    B|    C|  16|
|    B|    D|  10|
|    C|    D|  10|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

***EDIT***
I came up with this solution. Any improvement will be welcomed.

```
val sumOf = udf((left_score: Float, right_score: Float) => left_score + right_score)

val left = df.select("T", "S").withColumnRenamed("T", "T1").withColumnRenamed("S", "S1")
val right= df.select("T", "S").withColumnRenamed("T", "T2").withColumnRenamed("S", "S2")

val joinDF = left.join(right, left.col("T1") !== right.col("T2"))
val outDF = joinDF.withColumn("S", sumOf($"S1", $"S2")).select("T1", "T2", "S")
```

Comment: Have you a least tried to do it yourself ? Cartesian products are very expensive to compute...

Comment: so you have just changed the title but it is still a cartesian join...

Comment: I suggest that you post your edit as an answer. You'll not get a better one

Comment: Still not satisfied with answer though. Need some improvement if possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("A" -> 4, "B" -> 8, "C" -> 8, "D" -> 2))
           .toDF("T", "S")

val df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("T", "T1")
            .withColumnRenamed("S", "S1")

val df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("T", "T2")
            .withColumnRenamed("S", "S2")

df1.join(df2, df1("T1") < df2("T2"))
   .withColumn("S", 'S1 + 'S2)
   .drop("S1", "S2")
   .show

+---+---+---+
| T1| T2|  S|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B| 12|
|  A|  C| 12|
|  A|  D|  6|
|  B|  C| 16|
|  B|  D| 10|
|  C|  D| 10|
+---+---+---+
```

Basically you do not want a full Cartesian product. Only all the possibilities where T2 > T1. This is what the join condition means in the code. Note that a Cartesian product generates n² records. Here you will generate n(n-1)/2 records. This is less than n² but still in O(n²) so it should be avoided if possible...

Comment: This won't scale. Spark will still examine if T1 is smaller than T2.

Comment: @eliasah nice comment, look at the answer in the latest edit. If possible give some suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately @SujitS if you need the exact value you'll be needing the cartesian. there is not way around

Comment: In fact your question is "how to make a Cartesian product?". We gave you a way, and told you that it is very expensive. There is not much more to say about that... Yet, if you tell us why you want to do that, we may find a way to avoid doing the Cartesian product altogether ;-)

Comment: @Oli Thanks for answer. :)

Comment: @oli What I am trying to achieve is to get pair of each row with column T and the sum of consecutive S for each row. Any help ?

Comment: This I understand. Unfortunately what you describe is actually a Cartesian product of column T with itself. My question is what do want to do with this data? If what you're asking is an intermediate step to do something else, we may be able to help you achieve that final goal more efficiently.

Comment: Problem is like I have 4 cluster (k-mean cluster). Each cluster point has this information: `[Entity,Email,DistanceToCluster,Cluster]`.
Now I need distance from each and every entity like in final `df1` in your example so that I could get a closest n entities related to the given query entity.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem then. What is the use of the clustering that you have here if you just want to compute the K nearest neighbors of each entity?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the performance (hint: it's not possible to make Spark perform well on big cartesian products), you can use cross join introduced in Spark 2.x

```
import sc.implicits._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("A" -> 4, "B" -> 8, "C" -> 8, "D" -> 2))
         .toDF("T", "S")

df.as("df1")
  .crossJoin(df.as("df2"))
    .filter($"df1.T" =!= $"df2.T")
      .select($"df1.T".as("T1"), $"df2.T".as("T2"))
      .withColumn("S", $"df1.S"+$"df2.S") // you can use udf here as well
```

The same result can be achieved with the inner join, which makes it compatible with Spark 1.6.x

```
import sc.implicits._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("A" -> 4, "B" -> 8, "C" -> 8, "D" -> 2))
         .toDF("T", "S")

df.as("df1")
  .join(df.as("df2"), Seq("T"), "inner") // this line is different
    .filter($"df1.T" =!= $"df2.T")
     .select($"df1.T".as("T1"), $"df2.T".as("T2"))
     .withColumn("S", $"df1.S"+$"df2.S") // you can use udf here as well
```

Answer (score 1):

**The solution I am suggesting doesn't require you to use `join` at all. But the solution is expensive too as all of the data will be accumulated to one *executor* for processing**.

My solution is to combine *inbuilt functions* such as `array`, `collect_list` and `explode` along with `window` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

def windowFunction = Window.orderBy("T").rowsBetween(1, Long.MaxValue)

df.withColumn("array", collect_list(array($"T", $"S")).over(windowFunction))
    .withColumn("array", explode($"array"))
    .select($"T".as("T1"), $"array"(0).as("T2"), ($"array"(1)+$"S").as("S=T1+T2"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you your desired output as

```
+---+---+-------+
|T1 |T2 |S=T1+T2|
+---+---+-------+
|A  |B  |12.0   |
|A  |C  |12.0   |
|A  |D  |6.0    |
|B  |C  |16.0   |
|B  |D  |10.0   |
|C  |D  |10.0   |
+---+---+-------+
```